# Align (CSS Rotated) Element to left of its container - HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, rotation, alignment, transform

I have a series of 3 SVG elements inside a wrapper element and I have rotated this wrapper by -90 deg with a CSS transform.

I'm trying to get it so the yellow containing block is pinned to the left of the screen, so I can then alter how far from the left (% or vw) this yellow wrapper sits.

I've reduced the size of the yellow wrapper element so it's easier to see the problem. The yellow wrapper must remain vertically centred like it is now.

I can't for the life of me get it stick to the left - the transform seems to be making everything a lot harder.  I need it so that even if the window is resized it stays a set % (or vw) from the far left - for arguments sake say 5% / 5vw.

P.S I'm using SVG text because it's part of a clip-path animation, but I have removed this code to make things easier to read.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/emilychews/pen/qojZae

```css
body {
  margin: 0; 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
}

#wrapper svg {margin: 1rem}
text {font-size: 1rem}
```

```html
<!-- THIS IS THE YELLOW BLOCK CONTAINING THE SVG ELEMENTS -->
<div id="wrapper">

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="40" viewBox="0 0 120 40">
    <rect class="masker" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="40" fill="red" />
    <text x="16" y="25" fill="white">Some Text 1</text>
  </svg>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="40" viewBox="0 0 120 40">
    <rect class="masker" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="40" fill="red" />
    <text x="16" y="25" fill="white">Some Text 2</text>
  </svg>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="40" viewBox="0 0 120 40">
    <rect class="masker" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="40" fill="red" />
    <text x="16" y="25" fill="white">Some Text 3</text>
  </svg>
  
</div>
```

Comment: what your question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a transform origin and then adjust the offset from the transform like this. I also removed the Flex properties on `body` to accomplish this correctly. You can adjust to your liking from this point.

```css
body {
  margin: 0; 
  /*display: flex; 
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;*/
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0);
  transform-origin: left top;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#wrapper svg {margin: 1rem}
text {font-size: 1rem}
```

```html
<!-- THIS IS THE YELLOW BLOCK CONTAINING THE SVG ELEMENTS -->
<div id="wrapper">

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="40" viewBox="0 0 120 40">
    <rect class="masker" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="40" fill="red" />
    <text x="16" y="25" fill="white">Some Text 1</text>
  </svg>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="40" viewBox="0 0 120 40">
    <rect class="masker" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="40" fill="red" />
    <text x="16" y="25" fill="white">Some Text 2</text>
  </svg>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="120" height="40" viewBox="0 0 120 40">
    <rect class="masker" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="40" fill="red" />
    <text x="16" y="25" fill="white">Some Text 3</text>
  </svg>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @bsk this nearly works but the when I reduce the window size the text elements disappear.  I removed the width: 25% that was causing this on the wrapper element but then the layout broke again.

Comment: Hi @TheChewy, I just updated my example. That should work for you now.

Comment: Thanks @BSK.  Really appreciate it

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left` on your `#wrapper` like this:

```
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: yellow;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
}
```

Comment: No that doesn't work I've tried that. I need to be able pin it to the far left, and then add the % value.  Doing that just means the left:0 value is not to the far left so 5% just adds extra to this.

Comment: yes I know but I just showed you that you can use left to move I think that you asked for a percentage too so it was obvious that 0 was the left

Comment: oh wow... does having a value of `left: 5%' move an element 5% to the left?  Wow. Thanks for clearing that up. As a user of the internet I am truly, truly grateful.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly it would be sufficient to remove the `justify-content: center` on the `body` element.

Why would you need it there anyway?

If the `justify-content` is removed, you can then use `padding(-left)` to move your wrapper more to the center of the screen